# Running a stored procedure that populates a temporary table and then selecting from the temporary table

Tags: php, oracle

I have a stored procedure that populates a global temporary table.

```
CREATE GLOBAL TEMPORARY TABLE temptable
(
...
)
ON COMMIT DELETE ROWS;
```

I want to run the stored procedure and then select the rows added to the temporary table.

```
$conn = oci_connect(...);
$sql = "BEGIN POPULATETEMPTABLE END;"
$stmt = oci_parse($conn, $sql);
oci_execute($stmt);
oci_free_statement($stmt);

$sql = "SELECT ... FROM temptable";
$stmt = oci_parse($conn, $sql);
oci_execute($stmt);

while ($row = oci_fetch_assoc($stmt))
{
    ...
}

oci_free_statement($stmt);
oci_close($conn);
```

That code fetches no rows.  So I decided to put the select in the same round trip to the database:

```
$conn = oci_connect(...);
$sql = "
    BEGIN POPULATETEMPTABLE END;
    SELECT ... FROM temptable
"
$stmt = oci_parse($conn, $sql);
oci_execute($stmt);

while ($row = oci_fetch_assoc($stmt))
{
    ...
}

oci_free_statement($stmt);
oci_close($conn);
```

And that gives me error:

```
PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "SELECT"
```

If I put the SELECT inside the BEGIN ... END; then I get this error:

```
PLS-00428: an INTO clause is expected in this SELECT statement
```

How do I run a stored procedure that populates a temporary table and then select from it in PHP?

It works in SQL Developer, just not in PHP.

Using:

```
PHP 8.1.4
Oracle 19.0.0.0.0
```

Comment: I'm always a bit suspicious of persistent connections - which you really need with PHP+Oracle - but you've redacted the connect statement.....and even if its a oci_connect() then things could be complicated by DRCP.

Comment: yes, is oci_connect - have change post to include it

Comment: Do you have any commit/rollback in the procedure? If so, then you need to specify `on commit preserve rows` in the GTT definition

Comment: The temporary table is setup with `ON COMMIT DELETE ROWS`.  Post now edited to show that.

Comment: If DRCP is enabled with POOL_BOUNDARY as STATEMENT, that might explain why this is not working.

Comment: Use `ON COMMIT PREVERSE ROWS` and ensure that your OCI isn't disconnecting between the procedure call and the select.

Comment: Assuming that the temp table is needed (that's pretty unusual in Oracle), would it be possible for your stored proc to populate the table and then return a `sys_refcursor` rather than issuing a subsequent query from your application?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first issue is because `oci_execute()` commits by default, so any rows inserted by the call to `POPULATETEMPTABLE` are cleaned up by the `ON COMMIT DELETE ROWS;` definition.

Fix this by changing to:

```
$sql = "BEGIN POPULATETEMPTABLE END;"
$stmt = oci_parse($conn, $sql);
oci_execute($stmt, OCI_NO_AUTO_COMMIT);
```

The secondary issue about putting the SELECT in the PL/SQL block is because this is invalid PL/SQL.  Use a REF CURSOR or an IMPLICIT RESULT SET.  See the OCI8 doc or [The Underground PHP and Oracle Manual](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/database-technologies/php/201212-ug-php-oracle-1884760.pdf)

Comment: Great link to that online manual - cheers